# SSRS repeat subgrid for each child record

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am creating a report for CRM 2011 to show information about quotes and the related quote details records. So I have the main body of the report and I have created a subreport for the quote details section.

I've seen a report before where within the subreport it essentially repeated it for each child record, but for mine I can only get it to show the first one. Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to get it to show all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a tablix where each details rows of tablix would correspond to you master data lets say quotaID. Now, in this details row, include a sub-report which has a parameter quotaID which it would get from the tablix's details row and would generate details with that quota.

See this for some more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa337490(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks that did the job. The list tool was the one that I got it working with. Thanks again